# How to fix this message error that i cant create table using script?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just want to make a new table in database, when I create table just got some messages like

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near 'tbl_invoice'".

So my question is where do I start to make a new table?

```
use master
use db_penjualan

create table tbl_invoice (
no_invoice varchar primary key (10),
jenis_pembayaran varchar(25),
user_generate varchar (10),
tgl_terbit date not null )
;
```

Messages

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near
>   'tbl_invoice'.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: It looks like you are missing semicolons at the end of your `use` statements.

Comment: Why two `use` commands in one session?? why write `Use Master` when you want to create table in target database `db_penjualan`

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with primary key declaration syntax. Write it as:

```
use db_penjualan
Go

create table tbl_invoice (
no_invoice varchar(10),
jenis_pembayaran varchar(25),
user_generate varchar (10),
tgl_terbit date not null ,
primary key(no_invoice)--define primary key col here
)
;
```